# Saving a particular field of a related entities with Entity Reference

Tags: views, entities

Using Drupal 7, using entity and entity reference i have created 2 entities: --*Aircraft reservation (date, user, aircraft categorie)
*Aircraft categories (name)

I have created a view (entity reference view) to list all aircraft categories.

Aircraft reservation reference aircraft categories.
In the form subbmission of Aircraft reservation i can see the list of the categories. The reference link with the view work great.

[image]

But when i submit the form, instead of having the categorie of the aircraft which i has selected saved, i have the details of the entity that present the categorie which i had selected.

With other words, Instead of saving the value of the field name of the categorie, drupal save the details of the entity.

[image]

How can i fix that ? Thanks for all !

Answer (score 0):

I think the content is saved correctly but displayed wrong. Try to change your View which displays the results (the table). On the field for the entity reference, you should have an option to change the **Formatter** of the displayed entity. I think you have currently "Rendered entity" selected. Try to change to **Label** to only show the title of the referenced entity.

[image]

You could also display a different **View mode** for the rendered entity to show more/different fields. Check the [Display Suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds) Module for this.

Comment: Thanks for your replay, the formatter is setted to label. i will explore the display suite module maybe it fix the problem.